# Transpile Non-imported Typescript Files in Serverless Framework

Tags: typescript, nestjs, serverless-framework, serverless, typeorm

How can I enable the option to transpile non-imported typescript files. In my NestJS project, serverless framework skips typeorm migration files as they are not imported anywhere in project. I can make it work by manually importing migrations in one of the file.

Is there any option in `tsconfig.json` that automatically transpile non-imported file?

Here is my tsconfig.json file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "removeComments": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  }
}
```

My typeorm migration files are located in `src/migrations` directory and they run automatically as `migrationsRun` is `true`.

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { join } from "path";

export const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {

    type: 'mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    username: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'database_name',

    entities: [join(__dirname, './../**/**.entity{.ts,.js}')],
    migrations: [join(__dirname, './../migrations/*{.ts,.js}')],
    cli: {
        migrationsDir: 'src/migrations',
    },
    synchronize: false,
    // Run migrations automatically,
    migrationsRun: true,
    logging: true,
};
```

My migrations directory is `src/migrations` but they do not transpile into `dist/src/migrations` directory when I deploy via Serverless framework.